# 2sxc DNN - How to get name of content type field in cshtml?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am working on 2sxc app which will be used in several languages. There is a lot of content type fields which has labels (names) and values (content). I know how to use multilingual options for values (content) and it works pretty nice. 
I am wondering is there any way to get translation of labels for content type fields in Razor views. There is option to translate that names using 2sxc backend but i can't find way how to write that in my views (cshtml files).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go for this is to check the Type. So basically each entity, when used `AsEntity(...).Type` gives you a type object. This has Attributes of the type `AttributeDefinition` which has a `Name` - the official name - and Metadata.

For what you want to do, is you want to pick the attribute of the right name, then look in the Metadata for the item which will give you the translated name. It's a bit complex, but straight forward.

Here the pseudo code:

```
function getTranslatedName(IEntity entity, string field)
{
  var attribs = entity.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == field);
  var basicMeta = attrib.Metadata
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type.StaticName == "@All");
  return basicMeta?.GetBestValue("Name");
}
```